# Unable to read values from profile in Spring 1.3.6

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring-boot 1.3.6 . When I configure profiles,it's not able to read values from properties file under profiles folder. However the profile config works fine with Spring-boot 1.2.2.

Comment: Could you provide more details about the issue? Like errors if happening, the code you're using to read the properties, the given properties...

Comment: by default spring boot 1.3.6 reads properties from /src/main/resources  unless you define your own location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[spring boot external configurations](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

If you view the link you will see several ways you can use externalized properties in the order of importance.